# What's wrong with my give command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to give myself a box that makes me invisible to mobs while wearing it.
''It'' is a skull of my second account that is textured as a Cardboard Box :)

Command:

```
/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:DerpBox}{
    display: {
        Name: "DerpBox",
        Lore: [
            "Who needs state-of-the-art Technology",
            "when you got a Box"
        ]
    },
    AttributeModifiers: [
        {
            AttributeName: "generic.followRange",
            Name: "generic.followRange",
            Amount: -100,
            Operation: 0,
            UUIDMost: 62168,
            UUIDLeast: 860927
        }
    ]
}
```

I get an error saying

> Encountered multiple top tags, only one expected

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try merging the `SkullOwner` tag and the `display` tag into one section. I.e. `{SkullOwner:...,display:...}`

Comment: You are totally right ^^''. That was the issue. Thank you very very much

Comment: Ok, no worries. Like I have said, I have added this as an answer, so if this solved your problem, you can click the "accept answer" (The tick on the left hand side), so others can hopefully find the solution if they're having similar issues. Additionally, try not to load up the comment section with too many comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you have both the `SkullOwner` tag and the `display` tag in different sections. Since the `SkullOwner`, `display`, and `Attribute` sections are all NBT tags, these should all belong to the same block.

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags#Items), these should all be combined into one section, like so:

```
/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {
    SkullOwner:DerpBox,
    display: {
        Name: "DerpBox",
        Lore: [
            "Who needs state-of-the-art Technology",
            "when you got a Box"
        ]
    },
    AttributeModifiers: [
        {
            AttributeName: "generic.followRange",
            Name: "generic.followRange",
            Amount: -100,
            Operation: 0,
            UUIDMost: 62168,
            UUIDLeast: 860927
        }
    ]
}
```